# Typescript: how to prevent nested arguments of same name

Tags: typescript

I often use generic names for arguments in callbacks. For example, I might readily write:

```
someArray.forEach((el, ind) => {
    // ...
});
```

... where `el` and `ind` stand for element and index. The problem comes in when I have a lot of nested callbacks, and so I have to start labelling arguments like `el1`, etc., and my code can get confusing, and it can be tricky to unentangle all of my original `el` variables.

Is there a way to get typescript to prevent me from reusing the same name in a nested argument? I.e. I want to prevent e.g.:

```
someArray.forEach((el, ind) => {
    el.forEach(el => {
        // I want the second el to get flagged! 
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's perfectly valid Typescript and no compiler flags are provided to prevent shadowing out of the box. So your looking for a tool like eslint to catch softer code quality items like this.

Luckily, eslint has a built in rule for this [called `no-shadow`.](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-shadow)

Comment: Got it working now with ESLint. Thanks!